# How to add thumbnails to posts?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using the latest version of WordPress with the [Twenty Ten](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyten) theme. How can I add thumbnails to each of my posts?

A step-by-step guide would be helpful in this regard.

Comment: Just check [this post](http://nenuno.co.uk/creative/wordpress/adding-post-thumbnails-to-wordpress-3-0/). It explains everything clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, as a workaround, [Twenty Eleven](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/twentyeleven/) has this built in.

Comment: I have activated twenty eleven. My posts are still the same

Comment: You have to use the "Gallery" format.